# Base language German and default should be English

Tags: ios, xcode

Is set up the base language in my project to German. 
Is it possible to present English as the default language if someone for example in Japan uses the app?
And this, without adding Japanese and set the reference to English. 
English translation is available.

Comment: Does your app also include an English localization?

Comment: Is this for iOS or macOS?

Comment: Yes it has English and it’s for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do. It is up to the user. Run the Settings app and go to General, then "Language & Region". The language the user sees depends on the list of languages they have under "Preferred Language Order".

In your case, your app support German and English with German being the base localization.

If the user has added English to the Preferred Language Order list, and it appears before German does (or German isn't in the list), then the user will see English.

If the user has added German to the Preferred Language Order list, and it appears before English does (or English isn't in the list), ten the user will see German.

If the user has not added either English or German to the list, then the user will see German since it is the base localization of your app.

You can test this on a device or in the simulator. Set the main language to something other than German and English. Run your app. Then try various combinations of German and English in the "Preferred Language Order" list, running your app each time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will change base to English back.